# Android studio: Search name of developer in VCS Annotations Preloader log

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, version-control

In android studio VCS Annotations Preloader shows name of the developer responsible for line of code after control-click on gutter->Annotate.

Is their any way to search "Gutter Log" generated by VCS Annotations Preloader. I just want to check if I had changed anything in that file in last few commits but the size of the file is very large so its getting difficult to search my name in "Gutter Log" generated after Annotation.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to search through the gutter annotations, unfortunately.
However, even if possible, it will not cover the use case for 100% - annotation shows only last change to the line, so if someone else changed the same line you did recently, you will not see your name in annotations.

I would say that the better approach is to use Show history for the file, and search for your name in there (e.g. with speedsearch - just start typing with the Show history tab opened).